# Joomla 2.5 cannot upgrade extension because unable to save installation file in temp directory

Tags: joomla, sef

I tried to update my Artio Joomsef component on my joomla 2.5 but it seems cant be done because when i update it, it gives an error:
"infinite loop detected
unable to save installation file in temp directory
Unable to find install package."

why is that?
its working in my local, but i still dont know what might the issues.
i tried to change my tmp folder permission to 777 even, i know this bad, but i already revert it now. it still not fix the problem. what was the problem? anybody ever experience this?

Comment: Did you set your tmp folder correctly in configuration.php?

Comment: Yes, it was because of the tmp folder set and the permission not updated :) now its fixed thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the backend: Joomla System Information -> Directory Permissions.
Scroll down and see if tmp (Temp directory) is writable. By the way, see also for the Logs and compare their paths to the one of the Logs.
If any or both of these are Unwritable, then most probably you have set a wrong path in your configuration.
Usually in the majority of cPanel hosting the path is looking like this:

```
    '/home/account_name/public_html/tmp';
```

In goDaddy hosting is like this :

```
   '/home/content/**/*******/html/tmp';
```

The ** here are referring to the account numbers related to a godaddy
 hosting account. You can find the actual account directory, inside the goDaddy panel.

While in many plesk hosting the path is similar to the following:

```
   '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/tmp';
```